# webRTC datachannel is not working in chrome62

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am newbie to webRTC. I tried to  create a Chat application, sending a simple text message.
But getting this error:

**Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'
    at HTMLButtonElement.** 
Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
     <div class = "row"> 
          <div class = "col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">   
           <h2> Please sign in</h2> 

           <input type = "email" id = "usernameInput" 
              class = "form-control formgroup" placeholder = "Enter Name" 
              required = "" autofocus = "" title="please Enter name">
           <button id = "loginBtn" class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btnblock">
              Sign in</button> 
        </div> 
     </div> 

  </div>

  <div id = "callPage" class = "call-page container">

     <div class = "row"> 
        <div class = "col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center"> 
           <div class = "panel panel-primary"> 
              <div class = "panel-heading">Text chat</div> 
              <div id = "chatarea" class = "panel-body text-left"></div> 
           </div> 
        </div> 
     </div>


     <div class = "row text-center"> 
        <div class = "col-md-12"> 
           <input id = "msgInput" type = "text" placeholder = "Enter message" /> 
           <button id = "sendMsgBtn" class = "btn-success btn">Send</button> 
        </div> 
     </div>

  </div> 

  <script >


        var name; 
        var connectedUser; 

        var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000'); 

        conn.onopen = function () { 

        console.log("Connected to the signaling server");
        };

        //when we got a message from a signaling server 
        conn.onmessage = function (msg) { 
        console.log("Got message", msg.data); 
        var data =JSON.parse( msg.data); 
        //    console.log(data.type);

        switch(data.type) { 
              case "login": 

              handleLogin(data.success);

              break; 
              //when somebody wants to call us 
              case "offer": 
              handleOffer(data.offer, data.name); 
              break; 
              case "answer": 
              handleAnswer(data.answer); 
              break; 
              //when a remote peer sends an ice candidate to us 
              case "candidate": 
              handleCandidate(data.candidate); 
              console.log('candidate');
              break; 
              case "leave": 
              handleLeave(); 
              break; 
              default: 
              break; 
        } 
        }; 

        conn.onerror = function (err) { 
        console.log("Got error", err); 
        }; 

        //alias for sending JSON encoded messages 
        function send(message) { 

        //attach the other peer username to our messages
        if (connectedUser) { 
              message.name = connectedUser; 
        } 

        conn.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
        };


        var loginPage = document.querySelector('#loginPage'); 
        var usernameInput = document.querySelector('#usernameInput'); 
        var loginBtn = document.querySelector('#loginBtn'); 

        var callPage = document.querySelector('#callPage'); 
        var callToUsernameInput = document.querySelector('#callToUsernameInput');
        // var callBtn = document.querySelector('#callBtn'); 

        // var hangUpBtn = document.querySelector('#hangUpBtn'); 
        var msgInput = document.querySelector('#msgInput'); 
        var sendMsgBtn = document.querySelector('#sendMsgBtn'); 

        var chatArea = document.querySelector('#chatarea'); 
        var yourConn; 
        var dataChannel; 
        callPage.style.display = "none"; 

        // Login when the user clicks the button 
        loginBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
        name = usernameInput.value; 

        if (name.length > 0) { 
              send({ 
              type: "login", 
              name: name 
              }); 
        } 

        });

        function handleLogin(success) { 

        if (success === false) {
              alert("Ooops...try a different username"); 
        } else { 
              loginPage.style.display = "none"; 
              callPage.style.display = "block"; 


              //using Google public stun server 
              var configuration = { 
              "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun2.1.google.com:19302" }] 
              }; 


              yourConn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration,{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]}); 

              // Setup ice handling 
              yourConn.onicecandidate = function (event) { 
                    console.log('enter into login');
              if (event.candidate) { 
                    send({ 
                    type: "candidate", 
                    candidate: event.candidate 
                    }); 
              } 
              }; 

              //creating data channel 
              dataChannel = yourConn.createDataChannel("channel",  {reliable:true}); 

              dataChannel.onerror = function (error) { 
              console.log("Ooops...error:", error); 
              }; 

              //when we receive a message from the other peer, display it on the screen 
              dataChannel.onmessage = function (event) { 
              chatArea.innerHTML += connectedUser + ": " + event.data + "<br />"; 
              }; 

              dataChannel.onclose = function () { 
              console.log("data channel is closed"); 
              };

        } 
        };

        //when we got an answer from a remote user 
        function handleAnswer(answer) { 
        yourConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer)); 
        };

        //when we got an ice candidate from a remote user 
        function handleCandidate(candidate) { 
        yourConn.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate)); 
        };


        //when user clicks the "send message" button 
        sendMsgBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 

        var val = msgInput.value; 
        chatArea.innerHTML += name + ": " + val + "<br />"; 

        //sending a message to a connected peer 
        dataChannel.send(val); 
        msgInput.value = ""; 
        });
       </script>
```

**server.js**

```
 var WebSocket = require('ws').Server;
    var Port= 8000;
    //creating a websocket server at port 9090 
    var wss = new WebSocket({port: Port}); 
    var fs=require('fs');
    var http=require('http');
    console.log("STARTED");
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {

        fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, pgResp) {
            if (error) {
                resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
            } else {
                resp.end(pgResp);
            }
        });
    });
    server.listen(3000);
    //all connected to the server users 
    var users = {};

    //when a user connects to our sever 
    wss.on('connection', function(connection) {

    console.log("User connected");

    //when server gets a message from a connected user 
    connection.on('message', function(message) {

    var data; 
    //accepting only JSON messages 
    try { 
        data = JSON.parse(message); 
    } catch (e) { 
        console.log("Invalid JSON"); 
        data = {}; 
    }

  //switching type of the user message 
  switch (data.type) { 
     //when a user tries to login 
     case "login": 
        console.log("User logged", data.name); 
        //if anyone is logged in with this username then refuse 
        if(users[data.name]) { 
           sendTo(connection, { 
              type: "login", 
              success: false 
           }); 
        } else { 
           //save user connection on the server 
           users[data.name] = connection; 
           connection.name = data.name; 

           sendTo(connection, { 
              type: "login", 
              success: true 
           }); 
        }

        break;

     case "offer": 
        //for ex. UserA wants to call UserB 
        console.log("Sending offer to: ", data.name); 

        //if UserB exists then send him offer details 
        var conn = users[data.name]; 

        if(conn != null) { 
           //setting that UserA connected with UserB 
           connection.otherName = data.name; 

           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "offer", 
              offer: data.offer, 
              name: connection.name 
           }); 
        } 

        break;

     case "answer": 
        console.log("Sending answer to: ", data.name); 
        //for ex. UserB answers UserA 
        var conn = users[data.name]; 

        if(conn != null) { 
           connection.otherName = data.name; 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "answer", 
              answer: data.answer 
           }); 
        } 

        break;

     case "candidate": 
        console.log("Sending candidate to:",data.name);
        var conn = users[data.name];  

        if(conn != null) { 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "candidate", 
              candidate: data.candidate 
           }); 
        } 

        break;

     case "leave": 
        console.log("Disconnecting from", data.name); 
        var conn = users[data.name]; 
        conn.otherName = null; 

        //notify the other user so he can disconnect his peer connection 
        if(conn != null) { 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "leave"
           });
        }  

        break;

     default: 
        sendTo(connection, { 
           type: "error", 
           message: "Command not found: " + data.type 
        }); 

        break;

        }  
    });

    //when user exits, for example closes a browser window 
    //this may help if we are still in "offer","answer" or "candidate" state 
    connection.on("close", function() { 

    if(connection.name) { 
        delete users[connection.name]; 

     if(connection.otherName) { 
        console.log("Disconnecting from ", connection.otherName); 
        var conn = users[connection.otherName]; 
        conn.otherName = null;

        if(conn != null) { 
           sendTo(conn, { 
              type: "leave" 
           }); 
                }  
            } 
        } 
    });

     connection.send(JSON.stringify("Hello world"));

    });

    function sendTo(connection, message) { 
    connection.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
    }
```

I have searched many posts and tried removing "{optional: [{RtpDataChannels: true}]}" ,set reliable=false. But still facing the same problem.Is it the chrome version problem? I am using Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (32-bit) of chrome.

Comment: Did it ever worked before chrome-62 ? Before calling `dataChannel.send` make sure data channel is opened. Check flag `dataChannel.readyState` or handler `dataChannel.onopen`.

Comment: I checked dataChannel.readystate. It is in connecting(Indicates that the connection is not yet active. This is the initial state.) state, data channel is not yet opened. What is the problem?

Comment: There could be multiple reasons(Latency/TURN/ICE/SDP...). You must handle all those failures/race conditions. Check iceConnection & peerConnection states. In best practice, if data channel is not ready queue the data in local memory and flush it on `dataChannel.onopen` event.